# Probability: k items assigned to n slot, find Pr. that at least 1 slot contains more than 1 item

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following, rephrased problem is from the book "Introduction to Probability" on p.35.

I have no solution to this problem and I'm not sure if my solution is correct.

No homework, independent self-study!

> Problem:
>   The telephone numbers of k people are randomly and independently assigned to n locations with equal probability (one location can contain more than one number). What is the probability that at least one location contains more than one number?

My solution:
Solve the problem by computing the probability that exactly 0 and exactly 1 location(s) contain more than one number, respectively.

- number of possible outcomes: $n^k$
- number of favourable outcomes for exactly 0 location containing more than one number: $\binom{n}{k}k!= n \binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!$
- number of favourable outcomes for exactly 1 location containing more than one number: $\sum_{\color{red}{i=2}}^{k} n \binom{n-1}{k-i}(k-i)!$

Thus, the result should be: $1 - \frac{1}{n^k} \sum_{\color{red}{i=1}}^{k} n \binom{n-1}{k-i}(k-i)!$

Here is some R code for the case $n=10$ and $k=5$, giving a probability of 0.639. Of course, that will blow up for large n, but not the matter here.

```
n <- 10
k <- 5
sum <- 0.0
for(i in 1:k) sum <- sum + n*choose(n-1, k-i)*factorial(k-i)
1.0 - sum/n^k
> 0.639
```

Question: Is my approach correct?

**EDIT**

As Henry said, I'm calculating the probability that at least *two* locations contain more than one number. Hence, the correct solution should be $1-\frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k}*k!$, I guess.

Comment: [Probability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is about the measure-theoretic foundations of stochastics. The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about calculating a specific probability. Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/the-tags-probability-and-probability-theory).

Comment: You seem to answering the the question that at least ***two*** locations contain more than one number

Comment: @ Henry: Damn, you are right! That's why it was harder than first expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your correction looks correct.

If you want to simulate this in R, the following will do so rather inefficiently

```
people <- 5
locations <- 10
samplesize <- 10000
atleast1 <- 0
set.seed(2014)
for (i in 1:samplesize){
   if(length(unique(sample(locations, people , replace=TRUE))) != people){
       atleast1 <- atleast1 + 1 
       }
   }
atleast1 / samplesize
1 - choose(locations, people) * factorial(people) / locations^people
```

giving

```
> atleast1 / samplesize
[1] 0.7007
> 1 - choose(locations, people) * factorial(people) / locations^people
[1] 0.6976
```

which are reasonably close

Comment: Nice, to just simulate it didn't occur to me, although it's pretty straightforward. Reminds me that I can often use simulation to check for the correctness of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that both the "telephone numbers" and the "locations" are distinct, your solution (after Henry's remark) is **absolutely correct**. It is probably stated in the problem, but it must be true that $k \leq n$, else the probability is $1$. This is commonly known as the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). You can read more if you're interested.

If the telephone numbers are considered *not distinct*, then the number of arrangements such that every location contains at most $1$ number (i.e. the complementary event) is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}$ and the total number of arrangements is $\displaystyle \binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$ (look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)), giving us a result of $\displaystyle 1 - \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}}$.